# HSQL: run it as HQSL database engine server?

Tags: java, spring, database, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am trying to start hsqldb in "HSQL Database Engine Server" mode. but I am getting `sql Transient Connection Exception: Connection Refused`.
I want to do this to be able to connect to hsql inside my java application and with a database management software like dbeaver at the same time, to view the database/tables as the application is doing its job.
Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I do it all the time with HyperSQL 2.5. I typically start the db server with: `java -cp jdbc-drivers/hsqldb-2.5.1.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:db3/db3 --dbname.0 xdb`. Then I can have many simultaneous clients looking at the same data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.